# Unhandled apple file control error(1) while trying to copy photos

Tags: 19.10, iphone

I'm trying to copy photos from my iPhone 7 Plus to my Ubuntu 19.10. I've managed to connect it to my PC and I can see the folders as well, but when I'm trying to copy, it copies some files but not all of them. It gives me the error:

```
Unhandled Apple File Control error (1)
```

Comment: Does this resource help answer your question? https://fuelledbykrawu.wordpress.com/2011/10/29/how-to-fix-unhandled-error-lockdown-in-ubuntu-while-attempting-to-mount-an-ios5-device/

Comment: No, I've already tried it, I managed to pair the device. but I cannot copy all the files.

Answer (score 2):

I have sometimes experienced the `Unhandled Apple File Control error` on my Fedora 29 Workstation x86_64 with an iPad mini 2 (iOS 12.4.1).

My solution, following the [Apple iPod, iPad, iPhone](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Apple_iPod,_iPad,_iPhone#:%7E:text=Unhandled%20Apple%20File%20Control%20error,-If%20you%27re&text=%22%2C%20then%20it%20is%20possible%20that,back%20and%20reconnect%20the%20device.) Gentoo page, is to unplug the USB cable and plug it back again. After that, I can access the app folders of the iPad normally as usual.

Sometimes you need to re-plug the USB cable several times. Do not forget to press *Trust* on the iPad to trust your computer, and also input the lock-screen password on the iPad (if you have one). It would be better keep the iPad's screen unlocked during the file transfer.

I hope that my experience is helpful for your or other people's problem.